# PHP: Display data from Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I working on a program and coming up with some annoying issue.  I am trying to display data from an array.  I copied the format from another array I setup and it works perfect.  The only difference is I am gathering a lot more data...

Calling the function:

```
$data1 = display_orders($_SESSION['user_id'], $limit, 'fName', 'lName', 'VendorName',      'DateRequested', 'Shipping', 'VendorNumber', 'VendorFax', 'VendorAddress', 'VendorCity', 'VendorState', 'VendorZip', 'EquipmentConsumable', 'GasType', 'GasLocation', 'UNMTag', 'EquipmentLocation', 'index', 'totalcost', 'Approved', 'Shipped');
```

The Function itself

```
<?php
function display_orders($user_id, $limit)
{
    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;
    $limit = (int)$limit;

        $func_num_args = func_num_args();
        $func_get_args = func_get_args();

//  print_r($func_get_args);
                if ($func_num_args > 1)
                        {
                                unset($func_get_args[0]);
                unset($func_get_args[1]);


                                $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';

                for($x = 0; $x < $limit; $x++)
                {   

                $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields  FROM  `users` ,  `vendor` WHERE $user_id = users.id AND $user_id = vendor.user_id ORDER BY vendor.DateRequested DESC"));
                }
                return $data;
            }

}

?>
```

So now i try to echo the data out:

```
echo $data1['VendorName'];
```

I get no output.

If I do the following:

```
print_r ($data1);
```

I get output!

Array ( [0] => Array ( [fName] => admin [lName] => test [VendorName] => Newegg [DateRequested] => 2013-09-19 [Shipping] => Standard [VendorNumber] => NA [VendorFax] => NA [VendorAddress] => NA [VendorCity] => NA [VendorState] => NA [VendorZip] => 00000 [EquipmentConsumable] => Equipment [GasType] => [GasLocation] => [UNMTag] => 0 [EquipmentLocation] => Computer Lab [index] => 0 [totalcost] => 39.99 [Approved] => 0 [Shipped] => 0 ) )

But if i try to add a field name No data....

Any help and I would be grateful!

Comment: `echo $data1[0]['VendorName'];`

Comment: or simply 'view source' if this is output to a browser.

Comment: Use `echo '<pre>', print_r($data1), '</pre>';` for a formatted output of the array.

Answer (score 5):

As you see, `$data1` is `Array([0] => Array(...))`, so you'll need to call

```
echo $data1[0]['VendorName'];
```

This is because you are assigning data as `$data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo $data1[0]['VendorName'];
```

I suggest when using print_r you first echo `<PRE>` as it will help you to see the true structure of the array easier. In this case, the location of VendorName is one layer deeper than you are echoing.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the index `[0]`:

```
echo $data1[0]['VendorName'];
```